# Add reference ValueTuple in source of CodeDorProvider

Tags: c#

I have an application with the code:

```
CodeDomProvider provider = CodeDomProvider.CreateProvider("cs");
CompilerParameters parameters = new CompilerParameters()
{
    GenerateExecutable = true,
    GenerateInMemory = true,
    IncludeDebugInformation = false,
    CompilerOptions = "/optimize"
};
parameters.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("mscorlib.dll");
parameters.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.dll");
parameters.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.Core.dll");
parameters.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("Microsoft.CSharp.dll");
parameters.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.ValueTuple.dll");
parameters.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.Data.dll");
parameters.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll");
parameters.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("netstandard.dll");
parameters.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.Runtime.dll");
string source = "...";
CompilerResults cr = provider.CompileAssemblyFromSource(parameters, source);
StringCollection output = cr.Output;
```

But when compiling, return error referring to the following line:

```
List<(int line, string name, decimal salary)> _order = new List<(int line, string name, decimal salary)>();
```

> "Invalid expression term"

Help me please!!

Preview source with the error:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
namespace Dominio.Main
{
    public class OrderByTable
    {
        delegate IEnumerable<int> MethodDelegate();
        public IEnumerable<int> LambdaMethod(Table table)
        {
            List<(int line,  string NAME ,  decimal SALARY )> _order = new List<(int line,  string NAME ,  decimal SALARY )>();
            return obj2;
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you use Roslyn `CodeDomProvider`? Otherwise `CodeDom` will use build-in C# compiler, which stopped at version 5.

Comment: can you tell us what dotnet version you're working with?

Comment: I wear dotnet 4.5

Comment: I'm on linux, so no dotnet 4.5 for me but have you tried adding a `using System.ValueTuple` on top?

Comment: System.ValueTuple not is a namespace, is a type.

Comment: If you get the error on `= new List` have you tried creating a POCO and initializing your list with that?

Comment: I removed the ValueTuple and adapted the code. Solving the problem.
Thank's.